# CakePHP based Application throws 500 Server Error on requiring Cache-Class

Tags: php, cakephp, newsletter

I'm trying to run a CakePHP based Application.
this is it: [Newsletter Mailer v1.1](http://codecanyon.net/item/newsletter-mailer-v11/149365)

I'm trying to get this running here: mailer.dasministerium.com

But as you can see all I receive is a 500 Internal Server error.

I tracked this error down to file: `cake/libs/cache.php` line 203

```
$core = App::core();
$path = $core['libs'][0] . 'cache' . DS . strtolower($name) . '.php';
if (file_exists($path)) {
    require $path;
    return true;
}
```

where line 203 is: `require $path;`

To track this down I die()d befor this line, and got my die() message.
Die()ing after this line resulted in the 500 Error, but die()ing in that required file (`cake/libs/cache/file.php`) gave me the 500 too.
So the whole thing is really crashing at that require thing.

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 LTS 64Bit, PHP 5.2.4 (as apache module, NOT fast-cgi)

Any ideas how to get this running?

Thanks in advance!
David

---

EDIT:

After printing out all errors into the error-file i found this:
`PHP Fatal error: Class 'CakeLog' not found in /var/www/vhosts/dasministerium.com/subdomains/mailer/httpdocs/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 83`

Unfortnunately there is no reference at all to `CakeLog` in this file... so: wtf?!

---

EDIT 2:

```
var_dump(class_exists('CakeLog')); // this before the crashing 
                                   // require() returns true!
```

---

EDIT FINAL!

Its a CakePHP <-> eAccelerator issue.... SOLVED

Comment: how about looking at the apache logs

Comment: @dogmatic69 already checked them. with no result

Comment: @leo set recursively to 777, upvote wasn't intended... just misclicked, happens ^^

Comment: Your link goes to an activate page. Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: it was eAccelerator's fault. fixed it with a little hack...

Solution:

open `/cake/libs/cake-log.php` an scroll to the very bottom, then replace

```
if (!defined('DISABLE_DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLING')) {
    set_error_handler(array('CakeLog', 'handleError'));
}
```

with:

```
if (!defined('DISABLE_DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLING')) {
    $cakeLog =& CakeLog::getInstance();
    set_error_handler(array(&$cakeLog, 'handleError'));
}
```

that's it :)

Comment: Care to share the hack for others who encounter the same problem?  That's the point of this site -- to share learning experiences for both the asker and others with the same problem to benefit.

Answer (score 0):

That solution is for Cake1.3 (and newer maybe).

What about 1.2?

There is no line:

```
if (!defined('DISABLE_DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLING')) {
    set_error_handler(array('CakeLog', 'handleError'));
}
```

in cake_log.php file.

Comment: Please consider posting your query as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that cakephp 2.x may return http status 500 when there is no 'view' to the controller. It seems to be 'randomly occuring', as some Controllers without a view returns http status 200.

Anyway, to solve this http status 500 problem, ensure all your controllers has a view associated with it (you will see an error at the bottom of the page if there is no view associated with a controller).